# how to create a database object that provides connection without any databse locked exception

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my application there is a lot of database interaction, So I have created one database class that holds the database creation and connection and multiple classes which access this database class for connection.

Now my problem here is when these classes access the database class I am getting `Database Locked` exception, Googled a lot and some people suggested to create `singleton` class but I am unable to create such a class.

My Code:

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Database d=new Database(this);
        Abc a=new Abc(getApplicationContext()) ;
        d.insert();
      //  d.retrive();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Database Class:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private String Tablename = "Table1";
    private String Column1 = "RegionID";
    private String Column2 = "RegionName";
    private String Column3 = "Currency";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, "Test", null, 2);
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        //  db=this.getWritableDatabase();




        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        final String r_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + Tablename + " (" + Column1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + Column2 + " TEXT, " + Column3 + " Text) ";
        db.execSQL(r_Table);





    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
     public void insert(){
         try{
                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                cv.put(Column1, i);
                cv.put(Column2, "USA");
                cv.put(Column3, "Dollar");
                db.insert(Tablename, null, cv);
                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

    }
     public void retrive(){
         try{
         Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from Table1", null);

         if (c != null ) {
             if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                 //Toast.makeText(new MainActivity().getApplicationContext(), c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 System.out.println("Rows are:"+c.getCount());

         }


     }
         c.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){

             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
     }

}
```

Another class that access database:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class Abc {

    Context c1;
    public Abc(Context mcontext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        c1=mcontext;
    }
    Database d=new Database(c1);

}
```

Please help me and show me a wayout.

Edit*********************************************************Changed code
Database class:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private String Tablename = "Table1";
    private String Column1 = "RegionID";
    private String Column2 = "RegionName";
    private String Column3 = "Currency";
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static Database sInstance;
    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, "Test", null, 2);
        //db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        //  db=this.getWritableDatabase();




        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static Database getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new Database(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        final String r_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + Tablename + " (" + Column1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + Column2 + " TEXT, " + Column3 + " Text) ";
        db1.execSQL(r_Table);





    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
     public void insert(){
         db=getWritableDatabase();
         try{
                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                cv.put(Column1, i);
                cv.put(Column2, "USA");
                cv.put(Column3, "Dollar");
                db.insert(Tablename, null, cv);
                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

    }
     public void retrive(){
         try{
         Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from Table1", null);

         if (c != null ) {
             if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                 //Toast.makeText(new MainActivity().getApplicationContext(), c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 System.out.println("Rows are:"+c.getCount());

         }


     }
         c.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){

             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
     }

}
```

Main Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // Database d=new Database(this);
       // Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        Abc a=new Abc(getApplicationContext()) ;
        Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).insert();
        Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).retrive();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Abc class

```
import android.content.Context;

public class Abc {

    Context c1;
    public Abc(Context mcontext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        c1=mcontext;
        Database.getInstance(c1);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is all you need to work with DB (singleton for SQLiteOpenHelper):

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static Database sInstance;
    private String Tablename = "Table1";
    private String Column1 = "RegionID";
    private String Column2 = "RegionName";
    private String Column3 = "Currency";

    private Database(Context context) {
        super(context, "Test", null, 2);
    }

    public static Database getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new Database(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String r_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + Tablename + " (" + Column1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + Column2 + " TEXT, " + Column3 + " Text) ";
        db.execSQL(r_Table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void insert() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                cv.put(Column1, i);
                cv.put(Column2, "USA");
                cv.put(Column3, "Dollar");
                db.insert(Tablename, null, cv);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void retrive() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from Table1", null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                //Toast.makeText(new MainActivity().getApplicationContext(), c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Rows are:" + c.getCount());

            }
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Cursor retriveCursor() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        return db.rawQuery("Select * from Table1", null);

    }

}
```

So, you don't need you `Abc` class, just implement all the needed methods inside your helper. To get instance just call `Database.getInstance(context)`

**EDIT** How to work with that from activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Database d = Database.getInstance(this);
        d.insert();
        d.retrive();
        Cursor cursor = d.retrieveCursor();
        //do stuff with cursor
        cursor.close;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @nikis I have few doubts here. 1. `SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();` if this line is not present in `constructor` then control is not going to `onCreate`, your example also has the same code then how the control will go to oncreate. 2. by repetedly calling `getWritableDatabase()` don't we get database locked exception.. also can you please explain a bit on working of this singleton class.

Comment: 1. It will go to onCreate, since you plug-in your db at the constructor by passing it's name to super. 2 No, we don't, because: Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database

Comment: well, singleton is simple - every time you try to get it's instance, you will work with the same object.

Comment: In this case how do I call the methods that needs database connection. In above code I am calling `Insert` from main activity now I want database connection to call that one. How can I do that?

Comment: I have made a edit to the question and tried your procedure, Please confirm me if that is correct.. Sorry for asking so many questions.. I am newbie to android and learning on my own. Thanks

Comment: I've made an edit of my answer. You can write all the necessary methods inside `Database`, `Abc` class is not needed.

Comment: Thanks @nikis you answer is really helpful... Accepted as answer :) and +1 for your constant help.